# String Scope : regular heap vs pool

Tags: java, string

I know how String pool works and all. That said:

```
void doSomething1(){
 System.out.println("This string is now added to the string pool and will stay there even after this method returns");
}

void doSomething2(){
 String msg = new String("This string is now added to the string pool and will stay there even after this method returns");

 System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Is `doSomething2` better than `doSomething1`. Should this be encouraged, given that some Strings have a very low chance of being `reused`. The problem I see is in case 1, the string stays in scope for extended period even when it is not used again.

Comment: In general, you should avoid creating Strings using the new keyword as much as possible, and let the JVM do its job. All String literals are interned, so using the new keyword forces the unnecessary creation of a new String. Also note that `System.out.println(new String("a") == "a");` prints false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is doSomething2 better than doSomething1.

No.

> Should this be encouraged, given that some Strings have a very low chance of being reused.

No.

> The problem I see is in case 1, the string stays in scope for extended period even when it is not used again.

I think you are misunderstanding what is going on here.

The String `"This string ... returns"` is a String literal, and it is added to the string pool *once and only once* when the class containing those methods is loaded.

- The `doSomething1()` does not add a String to the String pool.  Rather, it uses an existing String (the one I mentioned above) that is already in the String pool.
- The `doSomething2()` method makes a fresh copy of the original String that existed the String pool.  You are correct that the copy created by `doSomething2()` is not in the string pool.  However, you are not achieving anything useful by creating the copy in the first place.  You are better off just using the original String.

Finally, it should be noted that the String in the string pool that was created when the class was loaded will stay there until the class is unloaded (if it is unloaded), or until the application finishes.  There's nothing you can do about this ... and there's nothing you *should* be doing about this.

(The situation is analogous to what happens with a String literal in C or C++.  A C / C++ String literal is represented as a sequence of bytes in the program's initialized constant area.  It will be there for the duration of the program run, and there's nothing you can or should be doing to try to reclaim the space.)

---

> But for the sake of understanding and completeness: Here is a big string which is only going to be used once and if I can keep it short scoped, why put it in the pool?

Because the JVM does not try to (and in the general case cannot) determine that the constant is only going to be used once.  That kind of analysis is difficult, and it is not simply worth the effort.

For any sensible sized String literal, it is *unlikely* make any practical difference that it is in the pool for the duration.  If the string literals are large enough or numerous enough that it does make a difference, then they should be replaced with strings that are read from resources on the classpath or elsewhere.  It is up to the programmer to make this call ... not the JVM.

Comment: `makes a fresh copy of the String in the String pool.` Shouldn't it be in regular heap and not in the pool? I am confused now.

Comment: Thanks :). I get what you are saying. But for the sake of understanding and completeness: _Here is a big string which is only going to be used once and if I `can` keep it short scoped, why put it in the pool?_

Comment: @rocketboy - To repeat what Stephen just said: "_because it's going in the pool as soon as the class is loaded anyways_."  The class loader finds the strings and adds them to the string pool _when the class is loaded_ (even if its a parameter to a String constructor).

Answer (score 0):

When we create string with new() Operator, it’s created in heap and not added into string pool while String created using literal are created in String pool itself which exists in PermGen area of heap.

String s = new String("Test");

does not  put the object in String pool , we need to call String.intern() method which is used to put  them into String pool explicitly. its only when you create String object as String literal e.g. String s = "Test" Java automatically put that into String pool.

Answer (score -2):

In case of Java 7 you can use a new method to do so. It will put string in the pool for our convenience.

```
    String myString="Hello StackOverflow";
    myString.intern();
    if(myString=="Hello StackOverflow")
    System.out.println("Equal");
    else
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

Comment: `intern()` is available even in earlier versions of Java.